# What are the technical differences between SO and other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Being the first and busiest site on the SE network, I suppose that there are some differences between Stack Overflow, and the rest of the sites. The one difference I'm aware of is the [Interesting tab](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: There are lots of customizations that only apply to a subset of the SE sites; it's not just "SO" and "everyone else"

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is running the same code as the rest* of the Stack Exchange sites.

There is, naturally, some degree of customization per-site.

On SO, you have:

- the [interesting tab](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) (and no active tab, though you can still [get at it](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active) for now)

  - meta.SO has [bugs] and [reqs] tabs, Stack Apps has the [apps] tab (I think that's it for custom tabs)
- code syntax highlighting for basically all the languages supported by [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

  - some SE sites have subsets of this (LaTeX on [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for instance)
- [User searching](https://stackoverflow.com/users) is a starts with match, rather than a contains (due to # of users)
- Stack Overflow's meta is meta.SO, which is a fully fledged site
- all other network sites have a ["proper" meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), with synced accounts
- ... except Stack Apps, which has no meta at all
- Some of the social sharing stuff is suppressed
- This is also true of all metas, SU, and SF
- Ads are served
- This is true of SU and SF too

Can't think of any other differences off the top of my head.

<sub>*[stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) are different code bases though.</sub>

Comment: One more: different question sorting algorithm for the main page.

Comment: @Tadeusz - that's the difference between the interesting tab and the active tab, bullet #1.